# Under what conditions exactly does SIGPIPE happen?

Tags: pipe, signals, fifo, read-write

Say we have a named pipe called `fifo`, and we're reading and writing to it from two different shells. Consider these two examples:

```
shell 1$ echo foo > fifo
<hangs>
shell 2$ cat fifo
foo
shell 1$ echo bar > fifo
<hangs>
```

---

```
shell 1$ cat > fifo
<typing> foo
<hangs>
shell 2$ cat fifo
foo
^C
shell 1$
<typing> bar
<exits>
```

I can't wrap my head around what happens in these examples, and in particular why trying to write 'bar' to the pipe in the first example results in a blocking call, whereas in the second example it triggers a SIGPIPE.

I do understand that in the first case, two separate processes write to the pipe, and thus it is opened twice, while in the second case it is only opened once by a single process and written to twice, with the process reading from the pipe being killed in the meantime. What I don't understand is how that affects the behaviour of `write`.

The `pipe(7)` man page states:

> If all file descriptors referring  to  the read  end  of  a  pipe have been closed, then a **write**(2) will cause a SIGPIPE signal to be generated for the calling process.

This condition doesn't sound clear to me. A *closed* file descriptor just ceases to be a file descriptor, right? How does saying "*the reading end of the pipe has been closed*" differ from "*the reading end of the pipe is not open*"?

I hope my question was clear enough. By the way, if you could suggest pointers for understanding in details the functioning of Unix pipes in relationship to `open`, `close`, `read` and `write` operations, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your example is using a `fifo` not a `pipe`, so is subject to [`fifo(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html). [`pipe(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) also tells:

> A FIFO (short for First In First Out) has a name within the
>          filesystem (created using mkfifo(3)), and is opened using open(2).
>          Any process may open a FIFO, assuming the file permissions allow it.
>          The read end is opened using the O_RDONLY flag; the write end is
>          opened using the O_WRONLY flag.  **See fifo(7) for further details.**
>          Note: although FIFOs have a pathname in the filesystem, I/O on FIFOs
>          does not involve operations on the underlying device (if there is
>          one).
>
> I/O on pipes and FIFOs
>      The only difference between pipes and FIFOs is the manner in which
>      they are created and opened.  Once these tasks have been
>      accomplished, I/O on pipes and FIFOs has exactly the same semantics.

So now from [`fifo(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html):

> The kernel maintains exactly one pipe object for each FIFO special
>    file that is opened by at least one process.  The FIFO must be opened
>    on both ends (reading and writing) before data can be passed.
>    Normally, opening the FIFO blocks until the other end is opened also.

So before both ends (here meaning there is at least a reader and a writer) are opened, write blocks as per `fifo(7)`. After both ends have been opened, and then (the) reading end(s) closed,  write generates SIGPIPE as per `pipe(7)`.

For an example of pipe usage (not fifo) look at [the example section of `pipe(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html#EXAMPLE) : involves pipe() (no open(), since pipe() actually created the pipe pair opened), close(), read() write() and fork() (there's almost always a fork() around when using a pipe).

The simpliest way to handle SIGPIPE from your own C code if you don't want it to die when writing to a fifo, would be to call `signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);` and handle it by checking for errno `EPIPE` after each write() instead.

Comment: the pipe(7) man page also says that "The only difference between pipes and FIFOs is the manner in which they are created and opened." so for this behaviour, it really doesn't matter which one it is (except that it's easier to do this experiment with a fifo)

Answer (score 4):

Writing to a pipe or FIFO that doesn't have a reading process is treated as an error condition; it generates a SIGPIPE signal, and fails with error code EPIPE if the signal is handled or blocked.

Comment: But not on the first write to the FIFO, right? On the first write it blocks until a reader appears and starts to consume. If that reader dies then when the producer next writes _then_ it gets a SIGPIPE, right?

Comment: @ChristopherKing, not the first write, but _opening_ the FIFO. fifo(7) man page says "Normally, opening the FIFO blocks until the other end is opened also." (but you can open in nonblocking mode)